# Cannot be sealed because it's not an override

Tags: c#, overriding, sealed

I've the following class:

```
namespace Warnings
{
    public abstract class BaseWarningIntField : IWarningInnerDataField
    {
        public string PropName;

        public string HeaderCaption;

        public sealed WarningInnerDataType DataType
        {
            get { return WarningInnerDataType.Integer; }
        }
    }
}
```

I want the last property `DataType` to be not overridable, since that's the base class for a warning-detail field of type Integer, so it needs to always return the correct type `WarningInnerDataType.Integer`.

Anyway, the compiler give me the following error:

> 'Warnings.BaseWarningIntField.DataType' cannot be sealed because it is not an override

But, as far as I know the `override` does exactly the opposite of what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Why don't you try overriding that method in your concrete implementation?  You might re-think this question after a quick experiment.

Comment: Just don't make it virual then, no need to seal it.

Comment: alternately use static read-only

Comment: @0A0D and methods too. See section 10.6.5 of the C# language spec.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

in `C#` all methods by default are non-virtual. You can't override non-virtual method in sub-classes. So leaving property as usual will safe you from subclass overriding it.

`Sealed` is a keyword used in class declaration for inheritance restrictions or is used to stop virtual chain of members of a class hierarchy. But again - this relates to virtual methods and properties.

Trying to override "normal" property in sub-class will result in compile error

> 'WarningIntField.DataType.get': cannot override inherited
>   member 'BaseWarningIntField.DataType.get' because it is not
>   marked virtual, abstract, or override

To answer you comment, I'll present some code examples to illustrate my point. You can't actually restrict derived classes from hiding a method or property. So next situation is legal and there is no way to overcome it (this related to virtual method and methods denoted with `new` keyword as well)

```
class BaseClass
{
    public string Property {get; set;}
}

class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    //compiler will give you a hint here, that you are hiding a base class prop
    public string Property {get; set;}
}
```

The same way you can't restrict of hiding a field in a class by local variable, so this situation is also valid. Note that compiler will also help you to note, that you are hiding class field in by a local variable. This also related to `readonly` `const` and simple `static` fields as well.

```
int field = 0; //class field
void Foo()
{
    int field = 0; //local variable
}
```

Comment: From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/88c54tsw(v=vs.110).aspx):  _You can also use the sealed modifier on a method or property that overrides a virtual method or property in a base class. This enables you to allow classes to derive from your class and prevent them from overriding specific virtual methods or properties._

Comment: @AustinSalonen thanks for noting. Forgot, that you can stop virtual chain by sealing. But again, this is used for virtual methods

Comment: Ok, I got it. But is there a way to block others from hiding my method? Presently anyone can do that writing one with the same name.

Comment: @Teejay I've added some explanations and codes to the answer you'r comment

Comment: Interesting.  So `sealed` specifically means "prevent this already virtual method from being overridden further", rather than simply "prevent this method from being overridden".